# Access Html TextBox Control in asp Button Click Event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried this:

Inside **AddClass.aspx**

```
<input type="text"  id="txtClass" value="ClassName"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Inside **AddClass.aspx.cs**:
When Button (ID:btnSave) is clicked:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a=Request.Form["txtClass"];      

}
```

And I am not getting value in string 'a' .

Is there any way of getting value of html textbox in .cs code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="txtClass" value="ClassName" runat="server" />

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = txtClass.Value;

}
```

Without the `runat="server"` attribute being added, the server-side code has no knowledge of this HTML control. Note also, that the property to fetch the content server-side for a HTML text input is "`Value`", not "`Text`".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `name` attribute in your text box,

```
<input type="text"  id="txtClass" name="txtClass" value="ClassName"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

than you will get the value on submit,

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a=Request.Form["txtClass"];      

}
```